# Why are post request params case normalized by the browser plugins like postman?

Tags: rest, post, http-post

I am testing post requests through plugins postman (chrome) and HttpRequester (Firefox).

From the backend logs, I notice that the parameter names are converted to lowercase. 
I thought the request parameters are supposed to kept case-sensitive. 
Why are these plugins normalizing the case?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with Name-Value being set under 'Headers' instead of 'Parameters', by mistake.